# Can I use GAS to create an event series with custom dates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a script that creates an event series for a non-regular recurring event. For example, if I have an event that occurs on 3/1, 3/2, 4/5, 6/1. I don't want to create separate events for each because I want them all to be linked. That way, if something is changed, it can be changed in all the events at once.
Can this be done in GAS? It seems that CreateEventSeries can only be used with predictable events, like "weekly on Tuesday".
My script will pull a list of dates from a Google Sheet column and create a reoccurring event series that happens on those dates.
Does this sound possible?

Comment: you can't Link them

Comment: What kind of "changes" are you planning to do? Can you provide an example of the kind of edits that you want to do to the events? Would you also edit the information in the sheet for example?

Comment: @FernandoLara, This is for school where we have a new, irregular calendar. The script is so teachers can add things like "music class" to their GCal for the year. But, if the time changes they would want to change it for all future occurances and not have to edit every single event. The info wouldn't be edited on the Sheet. The sheet just houses the rotating days and times.

Comment: There is no default way to do it as mentioned by Linda Lawton before, however you could implement a workaround, but that would mean having to manage events through a Google Sheet and update the event dates there for a script to automatically update them in Google Calendar.